# VB.NET How to automatically process a string or file after uploading it to my website (Activation Process)?

Tags: web, vb.net-2010

I developed a management software and need to activate it online.
I am a developer for years but new to the web development
My software activation process is as the following:

```
a.The client gets the software     
b.The client enters the required information    
c.The infromation will be uploaded to my website    
d.The information should be automatically processed and generate a value
e.The generated value will be sent to the client to allow the software to run 
f.The client information and the activation information will be inserted to mySQL
```

I don't consider this method as a good method but this is my initial understanding, I welcome any suggestion to get the activation process clean, secure, and somehow easy on me as I am new to web development

I just need a guide or a method for step (d and e)
I can upload and download using FTP method without problems
I can eliminate all that if you gave me a better solution

sorry I didn't put any code but I am asking for something logical and I need keys to get it done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions?!

Comment: I have read about JSON and APIs but I don't know where to start, all I need is just processing a value sent from my application and returned with another value from the web.

Comment: You can use Google Docs or google Forms instead of uploading and it is free, also the Apis are free and supporting Desktop apps integration, then you won't need mysql now because you can develop your own internal database with all clients and pieces of information locally on your machine.